# What is the maximum no of characters i can fit into an Excel 2003 msgbox?

Tags: excel

What is the maximum no of characters i can fit into an Excel 2003 msgbox?

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit misleading.  Message boxes should provide meaningful information to the user.  If your message is so long that you're concerned about its length, or if you feel it could spill over the size of the screen, consider adapting the information on the message.

You can put any length of message into a text box (within the limits of the string), I believe.  The real question is, what is it you're actually trying to tell the user and how can you interpret lengthy content into something meaningful?

Comment: +1 I agree.  Messageboxes are often not the best way to provide feedback to the user.  If you have to ask if your message is too long, it probably is.

Answer (score 1):

On my copy of Excel 2003, the first 1023 characters display and the remainder do not appear. There is no error message - the extra characters are just dropped

Answer (score 0):

I have seen messageboxs so big that they spill off the page with no way of dismissing the.